# Copy/Paste - Subscript out of range error

Tags: vba, excel

I searched and did not find an exact duplicate of my question.  Maybe it's out there but I did not find it.

I and using the following simple code to copy a range from one sheet to a range on another sheet.

```
Sub ApacheGetCopyOfLogList()
    Sheets("Sheet8").Range("B5:B92").Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Sheet10").Range("B5")
End Sub
```

I have also tried:

```
Sub ApacheGetCopyOfLogList()
    Sheets("Sheet8").Range("B5:B92").Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Sheet10").Range("B5:92")
End Sub
```

--thinking that destination range may need to be the same size, but that is not true.  I still get the same error.

It has to be something about how I am referring to the different worksheets.  I say this since the following code always works without fail:

```
Sub Something
    Range("L5:M1000").Copy _
        Destination:=Range("A5")
End Sub
```

I just can't see what I am getting wrong.  It's probably super simple!  But it's the end of a long day and I need some guidance.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the second, `Range("B5:92")` is malformed but overall you either don't have a worksheet named Sheet8 or one names Sheet10 or both. Note name, not codename. You probably have them as codenames.

Comment: Not true.  I know the difference.  I do have sheet 8 and sheet 10. Those sheets are code named something entirely different - "Training Log" and "Shop Employees" respectively.  I did catch that missing letter in the range but that is not the issue either.  Same issue even if I make it ("B5") instead of ("B5:B92").

Comment: Derp!  I totally blew that!  thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use [worksheet codenames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-codename-property-excel) instead of [worksheet names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-name-property-excel) the syntax is different.

```
Sub ApacheGetCopyOfLogList()
    Sheet8.Range("B5:B92").Copy _
        Destination:=Sheet10.Range("B5")
End Sub
```